# VB.net Delete a File after Creating Byte

Tags: vb.net

When I try to delete a Tiff file after creating a byte I get an error stating that I cannot access file because it is being accessed by another process. I am Printing the Byte after the fact if that matters.

```
                Dim image As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(strFile)
                Dim imageConverter As New ImageConverter()
                Dim Bytes As Byte() = DirectCast(imageConverter.ConvertTo(image, GetType(Byte())), Byte())

                Dim PageSettings As New PageSettings
                Dim FS As New FileStream("C:\clean\Packing\output.TIF", FileMode.Create)
                FS.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length)
                FS.Close()
                FS.Dispose()
                IO.File.Delete(strFile)
```

Comment: Why don't you uses `File.ReadAllByte()` instead of `Image.FromFile()` if you need the file bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement the [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) to dispose the object after you finish using it.

> The End Using statement disposes of the resources under the Using block's control.

```
Using image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(strFile)
    Dim imageConverter As New ImageConverter() 
    Dim Bytes As Byte() = DirectCast(imageConverter.ConvertTo(image, GetType(Byte())), Byte())
    Dim pageSettings = New PageSettings
    Using FS = New FileStream("C:\clean\Packing\output.TIF", FileMode.Create)
        FS.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length)
    End Using
End Using
IO.File.Delete(strFile)
```